# Should we use getters for a non-computed state property?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have been using vuex for about a week now.
I have the following state in my store

```js
state: {
    propA: "test",
    propB: 5.9
}
```

I want to access `propA` in my components. So I use the following

```js
this.$store.state.propA;
```

Everything works fine

But all the tutorials I watched and followed suggest of using a getter to access the state property as follows

```js
getters: {
    propA(state){
        return state.propA:
    }
}
```

and use it in the component as follows

```js
this.$store.getters.propA;
```

Do I have to setup a getter for every property in the state I want to access even though it is not computed value of the state property
It is more verbose to setup getters for every property and we can directly access using `this.$store`

Comment: The documentation states that using getters allows you to process your state data before it gets delivered - it works as a computed property that works on top of the state property you want to get. As long as you only want the plain state item, I see no downside on using the state directly.

Comment: Thanks for clearing my doubt. I got confused as many tutorials said it was a good practice  even though you don't compute anything to return a getter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is unnecessary to setup getter for every property.

Getters are only necessary when some additional computations are needed. From vuex [documentation for getters](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html):

> Sometimes we may need to compute derived state based on store state, for example filtering through a list of items and counting them

So, to access property in components, use just

```
this.$store.state.propA;
```

or, with [`mapState`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#the-mapstate-helper) helper:

- object-version:

  ```
  import { mapState } from 'vuex'

  export default {
    // ...
    computed: mapState({
      // arrow functions can make the code very succinct!
      propA: state => state.propA,

      // passing the string value 'propB' is same as `state => state.propB`
      propBAlias: 'propB'
    })
  }
  ```
- array-version:

  ```
  computed: mapState([
    // map this.propA to store.state.propA
    'propA'
  ])
  ```